# How to remove bluetooth device by clicking "x" when there is no "x"?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, system-settings, disk-format

I'm following instructions on [what to before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201065) and when attempting step 6 (Unpair bluetooth devices), I attempt to 'move the pointer over device that you want to remove, then click the remove (x) button next to the device name'. But there is no remove (x) button (nor anything similar):

[image]

I have tried

- left clicking, right clicking, and double clicking in all areas of the Bluetooth settings (on the grey areas, white areas, and the blue area), but no extra options/menus emerge.
- clicked 'Advanced', but that only gives three unrelated options
- read that it [could be a bug](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7336855?answerId=7336855021#7336855021), and attempted to click the bluetooth icon in the menu bar with option held down, but no 'remove' option is available

I am therefore not sure what to attempt next?

Note: running Catalina 10.15.6 (up to date)

Answer (score 13):

The answer (for me at least) was very simple: bluetooth needs to be **on** in order for the "x" to appear when the bluetooth device is hovered over. It's that simple: turn bluetooth on.

Comment: I love a good FacePalm moment ;) I've done it myself, we all have. This could always be useful for others in future, so thanks for posting it.

Comment: I wouldn't be too hard on yourself, the UI designers should have expected this!